# Вопрос касательно java Annotation и Reflection

Tags: java, java-11

Здраствуйте, у меня вопрос, У меня есть множество классов помеченые какой то анотацией, мне нужно все класы которие помечение анотацией засунуть в Set.
Пробывал с помощю:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections();


    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allProtocolMessages =
            reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(IntenseLabPacket.class);

    allProtocolMessages.forEach(aClass -> {
        crc32.reset();
        crc32.update(aClass.getSimpleName().getBytes());
        messageTypesMap.put(aClass, (int) crc32.getValue());

    });
```

Где `IntenseLabPacket` ето анотация, но ето работает только на java 1.8, а на 11 нет. на java 11 `Set` попросту не заполняется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
new Reflections("my.package").getTypesAnnotatedWith(IntenseLabPacket.class)
```

Comment: Понял, а пекедж как путь указывать или просто название папки?

Comment: нужно указывать как путь

Comment: Thanks it's work